flutter markdown issue: non-rectangle picture displays with white border in MarkdownBody
In flutter, I want to display a picture in MarkdownBody using imageBuilder, and it return Image.asset. However, my markdown background color is black and the non-rectangle picture's border is filled with white color. Do anyone have idea about how to make the background color same with markdown background color? Thanks a lot.
return MarkdownBody(
  
        styleSheet: _markdownStyleOverride(
            _getMarkdownStyleSheetFromPlatform(context), defaultFontSize),
        imageBuilder: (Uri uri, String? title, String? alt) {
          String url = uri.toString();
          var asset = getStickerAssetPath(url);
            if (asset != null) {
              return Image.asset(
                asset,
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
              );
            }
          }

          return Center(
            child: AutoBBSImage(
                key: UniqueKey(),
                src: url,
                maxWidth: imageWidth,
                onTapImage: onTapImage),
          );
        },
      );

picture with white border
I'm new to Dart and really don't know how to solve it.
